# Is it possible to detect if parent method is being overriden?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance, overriding

Consider this piece of code:

```
function Parent(){};
Parent.prototype.myMethod = function()
{
    return "hi!";
}

function Child(){};
Child.prototype = Object.create(new Parent());

var objChild = new Child();

//no override...
var output = objChild.myMethod();
alert(output); // "hi!"


//override and detect that in Parent.myMethod()
Child.prototype.myMethod = function()
{
    var output = Parent.prototype.myMethod.call(this);

    alert("override: " + output); // "hi!"    
};
objChild.myMethod();
```

Is it possible to determine if `Parent.myMethod()` is being called "naturally" or through "override" and in that case return something else?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V9qqX/)

Comment: `Object.create(new Parent());` - ouch! It should be `Object.create(Parent.prototype);

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the correction! I'm new at prototypal inheritance

Comment: Is there a real use case ? If so there might be a design problem.

Comment: How about `if (this instanceof Child) ...`? This does seem to be a design problem though... if `Child#myMethod` needs to do something different, can't you just do it there and forget about calling `Parent#myMethod`? If there is some common functionality they both need, maybe extract it into a new function in Parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to determine if `Parent.myMethod()` is being called "naturally" or through "override"

Not really (without resorting to the non-standard, deprecated [`caller` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller)). But you can detect when the method is called on an object that has a different `myMethod` property:

```
this.myMethod === Parent.prototype.myMethod
```

> and in that case return something else?

You really should not. Make it a parameter ([but beware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107221/at-what-point-does-passing-a-flag-into-a-method-become-a-code-smell)) that you expect something else, or divide the functionality in two different methods.

Comment: How can I make that detection? I didn't understand you completly, sorry!

Comment: Just `if (this.myMethod === Parent.prototype.myMethod) { /* the 'this' object doesn't seem to have a overwritten version */ } else { /* 'this' has a 'myMethod' that is not the inherited one from Parent */ }`

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you don't override the method, by passing `this` into the call function you call the function like it is `Child`'s function, you could do that even if you didn't inherit from `Parent`.